# Vectorization of matrix operation in R matching string patterns

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vectorization

I'm using the code below to create a matrix that compares all strings in one vector to see if they contain any of the patterns in the second vector:

```
strngs <- c("hello there", "welcome", "how are you")
pattern <- c("h", "e", "o")

M <- matrix(nrow = length(strngs), ncol = length(pattern))

for(i in 1:length(strngs)){
  for(j in 1:length(pattern)){
    M[i, j]<-str_count(strngs[i], pattern[j])
  }
}

M
```

It works great, and returns the matrix I'm looking for:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]

[1,]    2    3    1

[2,]    0    2    1

[3,]    1    1    2
```

However, my real data set is huge, and looping like this doesn't scale well to a matrix with 117, 746, 754 values. Does anyone know a way I could vectorize this or otherwise speed it up? Or should I just learn C++? ;)

Thanks!

Comment: First you should be able to achieve some speedup by using `stringi::stri_count_fixed()` instead of `stringr::str_count()`

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Out of curiosity, how did you know that? Just trying to learn.

Comment: Because your question is about speed, it would be nice if you provided a vector of relevant size (in addition to the current, small example which is indeed great to show the expected result!), e.g. `x <- rep(strngs, 1e6)` (more patterns as well?) and some ideas about desired timings. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You can use `outer` and `stri_count_fixed` as suggested by @snoram.

```
outer(strngs, pattern, stringi::stri_count_fixed)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    3    1
#[2,]    0    2    1
#[3,]    1    1    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some marginal improvement by removing the inner loop and switching to `stringi` (which `stringr` is built upon).

```
M <- matrix(0L, nrow = length(strngs), ncol = length(pattern))
for(i in 1:length(strngs)) {
  M[i, ] <- stringi::stri_count_fixed(strngs[i], pattern)
}
```

And then a more standard R way:

```
t(sapply(strngs, stringi::stri_count_fixed, pattern))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution, with `sapply`. Basically [snoram's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53046383/vectorization-of-matrix-operation-in-r-matching-string-patterns/53046641#53046641).

```
t(sapply(strngs, stringi::stri_count_fixed, pattern))
#            [,1] [,2] [,3]
#hello there    2    3    1
#welcome        0    2    1
#how are you    1    1    2
```

**Tests.**

Since there are a total of 4 ways, here are some speed tests.

```
f0 <- function(){
  M<-matrix(nrow=length(strngs),ncol=length(pattern))
  for(i in 1:length(strngs)){
    for(j in 1:length(pattern)){
      M[i,j]<-stringr::str_count(strngs[i],pattern[j])
    }
  }
  M
}

f1 <- function(){
  M <- matrix(0L, nrow = length(strngs), ncol = length(pattern), )
  for(i in 1:length(strngs)) {
    M[i, ] <- stringi::stri_count_fixed(strngs[i], pattern)
  }
  M
}

f2 <- function() outer(strngs, pattern, stringi::stri_count_fixed)

f3 <- function() t(sapply(strngs, stringi::stri_count_fixed, pattern))

r0 <- f0()
r1 <- f1()
r2 <- f2()
r3 <- f3()

identical(r0, r1)
identical(r0, r2)
identical(r0, r3)  # FALSE, the return has rownames


library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  op = f0(),
  snoram = f1(),
  markus = f2(),
  rui = f3()
)

mb
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq     max
#     op 333.425 338.8705 348.23310 341.7700 345.8060 542.699
# snoram  47.923  50.8250  53.96677  54.8500  56.3870  69.903
# markus  27.502  29.8005  33.17537  34.3670  35.7490  54.095
#    rui  68.994  72.3020  76.77452  73.4845  77.1825 215.328

autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

Comment: wouldn't we need bigger data for the tests to be representative?

Comment: @snoram Maybe. Sometimes (many times?) there are differences of code execution speed for small and large datasets. And not always the best solution to one problem size is the best for another size.

Comment: The actual pattern vector is 9000 values (basically the 9,000 most common English words), and the actual strngs vector is 13000 short phrases. So a rep(pattern, 3000) and rep(strngs, 4300) yields a matrix of similar size.

Comment: Right. But actually I see no reason why Markus'es solution would not continue to outperform the other solutions that have appeared as of yet.

Comment: Me either. It performs the operation in about ~30 seconds, which is a world of difference from the 20 minutes I was at double-looping.